# Android Kotlin Room different entities for different users

Tags: android, database, kotlin, android-room, entities

I'm facing small problem. I have an app (game) and I would like to create database using Room. Everything is fine as long as I have only one app user. What I would like to do is to have different databases or one database with different Entities for different logged in users. I'm using Firebase for authentication so I'm able to have userId (String) for each currently logged in User.
My Entity class:

```
    @Entity
data class PointOnField(
                        @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
                        var position: Int = 0,
                        var moveUp: Int = Static.MOVE_AVAILABLE,
                        var moveUpRight: Int = Static.MOVE_AVAILABLE,
                        var moveRight: Int = Static.MOVE_AVAILABLE,
                        var moveDownRight: Int = Static.MOVE_AVAILABLE,
                        var moveDown: Int = Static.MOVE_AVAILABLE,
                        var moveDownLeft: Int = Static.MOVE_AVAILABLE,
                        var moveLeft: Int = Static.MOVE_AVAILABLE,
                        var moveUpLeft: Int = Static.MOVE_AVAILABLE,
                        var x:Int=0,
                        var y:Int=0,
                        var ball:Boolean = false)
```

My Dao class:

```
  @Dao
interface PointOnFieldDao {

    @Insert
    suspend fun addPointOnField(pointOnField: PointOnField)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM pointOnField")
    suspend fun getAllPointsOnField() : List<PointOnField>

    @Update
    suspend fun updatePointOnField(pointOnField: PointOnField)

}
```

My Database:

```
    @Database(
        entities = [PointOnField::class],
        version = 1
)
abstract class PointOnFieldEasyDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun getPointOnFiledDao() : PointOnFieldDao

    companion object{

        @Volatile private var instance : PointOnFieldEasyDatabase ?= null
        private val LOCK = Any()

        operator fun invoke(context: Context) = instance ?: synchronized(LOCK){
            instance ?: buildDatabase(context).also {
                instance = it
            }
        }

        private fun buildDatabase(context: Context) = Room.databaseBuilder(
                context.applicationContext,
                PointOnFieldEasyDatabase::class.java,
                "easydatabase"
        ).build()
    }
}
```

Comment: you expect different Entities definitions per user? if not you could just replace database name with username, that would guarantee separation userwise

Comment: I have tried doing something like name: "easydatabase"+user.useId and passing user.userId to buildDatabase function... After creating second database (with another userId) I got errors...

Comment: I do it passing username in `buildDatabase`. Why this approach doesn't work for you?

Comment: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: PointOnField.position (code 1555 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_PRIMARYKEY[1555]) this is what I'm getting when I'm trying build database for second user...

Comment: did you destroy the instance of existing user database first? Companion Object is a singleton, so you cannot have two instances active at the same time, After you destroy the instance you should be able to either create a new database or open existing ones

Answer (score 0):

You can try to inherit all your `@Entity` from a class that contains `user id` information.
And write a code that will add selection by current logged in `UserId` as you expected.

```
@Entity
data class PointOnField(
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
var position: Int = 0,
var moveUp: Int = Static.MOVE_AVAILABLE,
var moveUpRight: Int = Static.MOVE_AVAILABLE,
var moveRight: Int = Static.MOVE_AVAILABLE,
var moveDownRight: Int = Static.MOVE_AVAILABLE,
var moveDown: Int = Static.MOVE_AVAILABLE,
var moveDownLeft: Int = Static.MOVE_AVAILABLE,
var moveLeft: Int = Static.MOVE_AVAILABLE,
var moveUpLeft: Int = Static.MOVE_AVAILABLE,
var x:Int=0,
var y:Int=0,
var ball:Boolean = false) : AuthorizedEntity()

class AuthorizedEntity(var userId: Long)
```